# Can't copy from vim to clipboard inside tmux

Tags: vim, clipboard, tmux

I am using vim vim 7.4, tmux 2.1 and ubuntu 14.04.
I can yank from vim and copy to clipboard when using vim directly from my terminal with "+y.
When I use vim from inside tmux, I can't yank-copy from vim anymore.
I tried set clipboard=unnamed in vim without success.
Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Have you tried ctrl-shift-c  and  ctrl-shift-v  to copy and paste in vim ?

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

### Prior Assumption:

I'm assuming you have `vim-gtk3` installed and have done the `set clipboard=unnamedplus` setting in your vimrc. Proceed to the solution now.

### Solution:

This happens when your display variable is not properly set. Try `echo $DISPLAY` and it should show `:0` or `:1` depending on your display. If you SSHed into your computer (say `A`) from another computer (say `B`) and then started tmux in `A` from `B`, the display variable usually gets set to your `B`. But you want it to point to `A`. Hence, the issue.

Easy fix is to set the correct display variable: `export DISPLAY=:0` or `export DISPLAY=:1` (depending upon the display).

Another fix is to simply close all the tmux windows and then restart tmux from within `A` computer's terminal itself. No incorrect displays would be set then.

Answer (score -1):

Try `set clipboard=unnamedplus`, it may help you in the Linux environment.